# Getting wildcards with Jinput->get

Tags: jinput

I seems `Jinput->get` removes all wildcards like `*` and `%`. Is that correct?

I have user input for a 'place of birth' of a person. So if someone enters `Amsterd*`, then through `Jinput->get` I get back  `Amsterd`, without the wildcard.

Is there something I do wrong? Or is it `Jinput`?

Comment: I think i found it:
But is it the right choise:
$geboorteplaats=$jinput->get('geboorteplaats','','RAW');
(sorry for the dutch lang. geboorteplaats means place of birth)
So i use the RAW filter.